# How to correctly define an object inside an array which is inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to change the values of an array created like this:

```
let newArr = Array(8).fill().map(() => Array(8).fill({ unit: null, highlighted: false, color: null }));
```

That is an array inside which is an array inside which is an object.
Whenever I try to change the values of the object, all the values corresponding to the first array outside the object are changed. If I write:

```
newArr[0][4].unit = "King";
```

Then all the unit properties of newArr[0] are changed to "King" (newArr[0][0].unit = "King", newArr[0][1].unit = "King", newArr[0][2].unit = "King".. and so on.) while I just want newArr[0][4].unit to be equal to "King".
I think the problem is in the way I am defining the array but don't know how to fix that. I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find a fix.

Comment: Use `Array.from` (or something like it) instead of `fill` for non-primitives

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Can you please explain? I'm a newbie to js.

Comment: Read the answer on the linked question

Comment: Got it. Thanks!